# *** internal error: unable to open jobserver semaphore '3,4': (Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified. ). Stop

Tags: c++, qt, cygwin, mingw32

I am trying to compile an existing qt application's code using mingw compiler. 
During compilation I am getting an error "*** internal error: unable to open jobserver semaphore '3,4': (Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified. ). Stop".

My current project is a makefile based project. Here I have one make file (parent.mk) that compiles all primary modules and then

### parent.mk

compilation steps
.
.
.
make $QT_CODE_DIR

Here in this QT code directory I have another makefile (child.mk) which has following content:

### child.mk

```
cd "qtcode_compilation_out_dir"

qmake.exe "product.pro" -r -spec win32-g++ 
CONFIG+=release

mingw32-make -w
```

If I try to run the make command manually for QT code then it works fine.

@Alexander: Thanks for the suggestion.

Please suggest if anyone has any idea about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time and read the [ask] page and then improve your question to contain a [mcve] (or at least the lines which throw this error)!

Comment: I am suspicious that the error is: "Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified." but I am not sure for which it is saying that.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out the exact reason of the problem and solution as well.

### Reason for failure:

The compilation command that I am using is "make" which is been aliased to "make -j2"and along with "mingw32-make -w" it was producing the error because mingw32-make is an obsolete make command and it doesn't support multi threaded compilation.

### Solution:

I just replaced the mingw32-make with make.